# how to make a CNN network described below by table and with diagram images?

Tags: python, keras, pycharm

I made a CNN network described into a research paper please tell where is wrong implementation I have done?

Because It shows the following error:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 68 from 5 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,5,5,8].

The description is provided in the following images:
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

the first image is described by convolution and Max Pooling details, and the second image descriptions follow the block diagram.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

path1="/home/sanjay/CASIA_B90PerfectCentrallyAlinged_Resized_with_140by140_Energy_Image/"
all_images = []
all_labels = []
subjects = os.listdir(path1)
numberOfSubject = len(subjects)
print('Number of Subjects: ', numberOfSubject)
for number1 in range(0, numberOfSubject):  # numberOfSubject
    path2 = (path1 + subjects[number1] + '/')
    sequences = os.listdir(path2);
    numberOfsequences = len(sequences)
    for number2 in range(4, numberOfsequences):
        path3 = path2 + sequences[number2]
        img = cv2.imread(path3 , 0)
        img = img.reshape(140, 140, 1)
        all_images.append(img)
        all_labels.append(number1)
x_train = np.array(all_images)
y_train = np.array(all_labels)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape)

all_images = []
all_labels = []
for number1 in range(0, numberOfSubject):  # numberOfSubject
    path2 = (path1 + subjects[number1] + '/')
    sequences = os.listdir(path2);
    numberOfsequences = len(sequences)
    for number2 in range(0, 4):
        path3 = path2 + sequences[number2]
        img = cv2.imread(path3 , 0)
        img = img.reshape(140, 140, 1)
        all_images.append(img)
        all_labels.append(number1)
x_test = np.array(all_images)
y_test = np.array(all_labels)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

print(y_test.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
#print(y_test)

batch_size =123
num_classes = 123
epochs = 80

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(136,136), activation='tanh', input_shape=(140,140,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(68, 68)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=64, activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(32, 32)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=28, activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(14, 14)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=10, activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(123, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Here I have 123 subjects of CASIA_B data set and each class have 10 frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs becuase of not having enough information about how set kernel size for convolution layer and how the max pooling works. I would suggest please have look on [this](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) where you can find detailed information about convolution and how to set kernel size. And also for [pooling layer](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#pool) as well.

And for your implementation,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='tanh', input_shape=(140,140,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(123, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 136, 136, 8)       208       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 68, 68, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 8)         1608      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 32, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         1608      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 8)         1608      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 200)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              201000    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 123)               123123    
=================================================================
Total params: 329,155
Trainable params: 329,155
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Update**

Your implementation is required custom layer which you can see in [this](https://github.com/nephashi/GaitRecognitionCNN) github repo. I am not sure that it is fully developed or not.

You need to download [this](https://github.com/nephashi/GaitRecognitionCNN/blob/master/layers/Conv2D121.py) file or may be clone complete repository and import like this,

```
from Conv2D121 import Conv2D121


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), padding='valid',
                 input_shape=(140, 140, 1)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D121(8, (5, 5), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(123, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Comment: ok, please see the first image third column for each layer 208 and 0 parameter value is there, how it could be possible. please change the code respect to it.

Comment: This what I created standard model, I don't know about your reserch paper which contains this model there might be some other information. Also share the link for the paper.

Comment: This is the link of research paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1077314217301674

Comment: by what formula output shape as (None, 136, 136, 8) can be related to kernel_size=(5,5) ?

Comment: ok, I understand that is with one stride 140-(5-1)=136, but this applies only with one stride

Comment: Stride=1, Kernel size = 5×5, Input depth=1, padding =0, output depth is 8 with this you can calculate for the first layer dimensions.

Comment: have you seen research paper? present in this link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1077314217301674

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA Please have a look on [this](https://github.com/nephashi/GaitRecognitionCNN)

Comment: ok, but I am not very much familiar with python code, may you edit and post the code here as per requirements?

Comment: may you see problem-related to other paper present in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888971/i-have-made-a-cnn-network-respect-to-one-research-paper-how-do-accumulator-work